# DateDiff in project server

Tags: project-server, ms-project, date

I am using project server, I've tried to subtract start date and finish date in custom field formula using **DateDiff** to calculate the duration.

I noticed the wired output is not identical to the build in duration field in project server !!!

What I did wrong ?!  I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project server defines the **duration** as

> The total span for working time for a task or project

The `working time` here depend on the current **project server calendar settings**.

So if you configured your calendar to have two days as weekends let's say Saturday & Sunday with 8 hours per day and you have a task that starts on Saturday and ends on Tuesday so the duration should be `2 days` as working time and not `4 days`.

So regarding your issue if you tried to use `DateDiff` function you will get the difference between the end date and start date that based on my above example is should be 4 not 2 like duration field value.

But if you need to calculate only working time depending on your calendar setting so in this case, you should use `ProjDateDiff( date1, date2, calendar )` instead of  `DateDiff`.

the `ProjDateDiff` will calculate the date difference between two dates based on the project server calendar settings.